# How to move a character over a display so that it appear to move with same velocity on all devices

Tags: android

I am designing my first 2-D game for android, In game iam moving a charater by 20 pixel each time whenever a loop is executing, by using a simple expression 
       x=x+20;
But the problem iam facing when i test my game on a phone with reso 320*480 with screen size 3 inch, the character seems to move fast, but while testing it on tablet character move slowly.
So i want to know how to move a character, so it will appear to move with same speed on both low end devices and high end devices, please tell me the logic, it will be more helpful if you explain the logic with some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using 20 constantly as your move speed. You need to generate the move speed relative to your scale factor. I don't know how you're handling aspect ratios differently, but for example I'll assume you're letterboxing.

Assuming you're letterboxing, you'll want to set your scale factor relative to your desire resolution, 320px in your case. So you should do something like:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

double scaleFactor = height / 320.0; /*// 480.0 if you're in landscape */
```

Then for you movement you can do:

```
x += 20 * scaleFactor; /*// 20 is your move speed, the scaleFactor will make sure it scales across device sizes
```

NOTE:
Depending upon how you handle horizontal and vertical scale you may need to factor in both to keep movement speed homogenous vertically and horizontally across devices, but this should be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the width of the device and then just divide that by something (like divide by 10 for 10% or 100 for 100%) and then have movement happen in relation to size of the screen.  The character will still move differently, but it won't be as different as a set amount.  To get the width of the screen you can do this:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Then do something like:

```
x=x+(width*.01);
```

to add 1% of the screen